# Create And Update parameterValues in Attask Api C#

Tags: attask, workfront-api

```
{
  "data": [
{
  "ID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "name": "Testing Project API",
  "objCode": "PROJ",
  "parameterValues": {
    "DE:Complete Sales Package": [
      "Parcel Register",
      "Signed Lease / Contract"
    ],
    "DE:Temp ID": 1234d5.0,
    "DE:Estimated Yearly Revenue": 0.0,
    "DE:Monitoring Required": "Yes",
    "DE:Lease Rate Annually": xxx,
    "DE:Project DC Size in W": 0.0,
    "DE:Sales Person": "xxC",
    "DE:Project": "xxxx - xxxxxxxx",
    "DE:IESO status name": "OPA",
    "DE:MicroFIT Rate": 333
  },
  "category": {
    "ID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "name": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "objCode": "CTGY"
  }
}
```

]
}

The Response i received when i create the project through template manually the parameter value named "DE:Complete Sales Package" its self as a custom filed with multiple check boxes so it has multiple values. how to create also update thorugh api..

My request is just like that with single values:
https://mycompany.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api-unsupported/proj?method=post&apiKey=apiKey&templateID=templateID&companyID=companyID&name=Testing Project API-12345&DE:Temp ID=12345

When Multiple check boxes selected what is the request ? iam using this 
getting error....
https://mycompany.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api-unsupported/proj?method=post&apiKey=apiKey&templateID=templateID&companyID=companyID&name=Testing Project API-12345&DE:Complete Sales Package=[Signed Lease / Contract,Parcel Register]

?? Any Help how to post this type of paramaterValue which has multiple values like :

"DE:Complete Sales Package": [
          "A",
          "B", "C"
        ],

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this through an update call the following should work.

```
https://mycompany.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api-unsupported/proj?method=post&apiKey=apiKey&updates={"templateID":"templateID","companyID":"companyID","name":"Testing Project API-12345","DE:Complete Sales Packag":["SSigned Lease / Contract","Parcel Register"]}
```

Comment: yes I did it just like that using json and its works... Thanks!